# XSL test for a value

Tags: regex, xslt

I want to do a test in XSLT 1.0 to see if a variable contains a web link.  I thought I would be able to do some sort of regex but it doesn't seem that 1.0 can do that.  Right now the code assumes that the attribute doesn't have `http://myserver.com`.  I'd like to be able to see if the variable contains `http://someotherserver.com/`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
.........
<xsl:for-each select="links/link">
<li>
   <xsl:text a href=&#34;http://myserver.com/</xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="@link" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</li>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to be able to see if the variable contains
>   http://someotherserver.com/.

There is no regex in XSLT 1.0.  And there is no variable in your code, so it's hard to be specific - but in general, you can use the [contains() function](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) to determine if a string contains another string.

---

For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="links/link"> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(@link, 'http://someotherserver.com/')">
            <!-- do something here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- do something else -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: `<xsl:value-of select="@link"` is where I need to determine if it contains "http"

Comment: @SDC `@link` is an attribute, not a variable. See if the example I added to my post helps.

Comment: Will that be true if the attribute contains `http://someotherserver.com/somepage`?

Comment: @SDC Why don't you try it and see?